# How can i use Tailwind directive @layer @apply, when i was in Tailwind CDN environment?

Tags: css, hyperlink, tailwind-css, apply, layer

According to the tailwind official doc:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

I can use @layer @apply in html file, i just need to import CDN, then write the <style> with type="text/tailwindcss"

```
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer components {
      .btn_style {
        @apply outline outline-sky-400 p-1 bg-sky-200 rounded-md font-bold;
      }
    }
  </style>
```

it worked, i can reuse class .btn_style, as my own components.

But, i want multiple html files can load this <style type="text/tailwindcss">

I tried to made the area: <style type="text/tailwindcss"></style> as an independent CSS file (style.css) . And when i use <link> to import style.css, it failed, how can i do?

```
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/tailwindcss">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a script? - Let's call it "mystyles.js"

This contains:

```js
    document.head.appendChild(
      Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), {
        type:'text/tailwindcss',
        textContent: `
          @layer components {
            .btn_style {
              @apply outline outline-sky-400 p-1 bg-sky-200 rounded-md font-bold;
            }
          }`
      })
    );
```

and include in each HTML file with `<script src="mystyles.js"></script>`

Then you can put whatever tailwind styles you want in the `textContent:` section of the script.